# Determine which VIF interface belong to which Xen domain on SLES12.1

Tags: xen, sles, hypervisor, virsh

As mentioned I have a list of `Xen Domain` as below:

```
Vm01<br>Vm02<br>Vm03<br>Vm04
```

And using bright network for communicating outside, After I launched 4 VM it automatically created 4 vif interface, but now I can not determine which interface is belong to which machine.

I am installing Xen hyper on Sles12.1 with kernel is: `3.12.62-60.62-xen`

Could someone help me on this case, as I am a newbie in Xen :(.

Thank in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Very simple that the vif interface name is the base on the domain id:

```
# virsh list --all
 Id    Name                        State
 0     Domain-0                    running
 12    xen_vm127                   running
 13    xen_vm126                   running
 14    xen_vm125                   running
 16    xen_vm123                   running
 17    xen_vm124                   running

:~ # ip a
23: vif12.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 512
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
24: vif13.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 512
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
25: vif14.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 512
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
27: vif16.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 512
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
28: vif17.0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 512
link/ether fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ffenter code here
```